# Resize image based on text height

Tags: android

I need to display an image and text on a single row. The image should resize based on the text height. I know that it's possible programmatically but is it possible to do this also only in XML ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/Image" ... />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/Image"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="47dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the views inside a parent view that adjust to the textview and make the imageview resize according to the parent.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <!-- LOOK HERE-->
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/Image"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="47dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="37dp" />

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/Image" 
    android:layout_heigth="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I haven't test it, but it should be something really close to this.

**EDIT:** Using an horizontal LinearLayout should give you a quick view of how is working and the in the linear layout you arrange with the toRightOf, toLeftOf, etc.